# How can I get a full url as parameter in a route

Tags: node.js, ejs

I need to get a full url as parameter to convert it in a qrcode. Once the url is in this format https://website.com.br/2k , I can't receive it as parameter in my node.js route

That's how I'm sending the parameter to ejs page

```
res.render("tutorial.ejs", { qrcode: '/qrcode/'+ link });
```

`link` is something like: `http://comp.co/32`

In tutorial.ejs, I render the qrcode calling qrcode route

```
 <img src="<%= qrcode %>">
```

qrcode route:

```
routes.get('/qrcode/:url',(req,res, next) => {    
    const code = qr.image(req.params.url, {type: 'svg'});
    res.type('svg');
    code.pipe(res);
})
```

It's not working. I think that happening because my qrcode route is getting something like this as parameter: `http://comp.co/32`

Comment: Did you try `req.originalUrl`?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(req.params.url)` ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi I posted it wrong, It was just qr.image(url, {type: 'svg'});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you make get request, you are basically calling

```
routes.get(/qrcode/http:/comp.co/32){...}
```

so router in the backend understands it as a route and it wont call your expected route i.e.
`routes.get(/qrcode/:url){...}`

**Solution:**

Url encode your url as  and try your code again.

```
var link="http%3A%2F%2Fcomp.co%2F32"
res.render("tutorial.ejs", { qrcode: '/qrcode/'+ link });

<img src="<%= qrcode %>">

routes.get('/qrcode/:url',(req,res, next) => {    
    const code = qr.image(req.params.url, {type: 'svg'});
    res.type('svg');
    code.pipe(res);
})
```

But better way to pass parameter is using query to avoid confusion, you can do this

```
res.render("tutorial.ejs", { qrcode: '/qrcode?url='+ link });


routes.get('/qrcode',(req,res, next) => {    
    const code = qr.image(req.query.url, {type: 'svg'});
    res.type('svg');
    code.pipe(res);
})
```

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can console.log(req) inside your qrcode route to see what data you can get from the request.